# Using dplyr to collect data and bind rows of the data collected

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

I am trying to use `rvest()` to extract some information. What I have is a list of links and I would like to bind the rows of the data collected together.

What I currently have is the following;

EDIT: heres the links without the weekend data

```
    links <- c("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-05", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-06", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-07", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-08", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-09", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-12", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-13", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-14", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-15", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-16", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-19", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-20", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-21", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-22", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-23", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-26", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-27", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-28", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-29", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-03-30", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-02", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-03", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-04", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-05", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-06", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-09", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-10", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-11", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-12", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-13", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-16", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-17", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-18", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-19", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-20", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-23", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-24", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-25", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-26", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-27", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-04-30", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-01", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-02", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-03", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-04", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-07", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-08", "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-09", 
"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-10")
```

Code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
x <- links %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  extract2(1) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  as_tibble
```

This gives the following error:
`Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=68].`

I am able to get the code working for 1 link however when I try to get it working for all the links I am running into errors. For example this code works:

```
x <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2018-05-08" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  extract2(1) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  as_tibble
```

EDIT:

```
from = "2016-03-04"
to = "2018-05-10"


s <- seq(as.Date(from), as.Date(to), "days")
library(chron)
s <- s[!is.weekend(s)]  
links <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=", s)



library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(naniar)

IPOs <- links[1:400] %>% 
  map_dfr(~read_html(.x) %>% 
            html_table() %>%
            extract2(1) %>%
            naniar::replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x == "-") %>%
            type.convert(as.is = TRUE) )
```

Comment: Try replacing your `read_html()` line with `sapply(read_html)`

Comment: I get this `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503` but I think that might be due to the list of links having weekends in them. I will try to see if there is a function to remove the weekends and try this again.

Comment: Or you could try it just with `links[3:4]` (1 and 2 are weekend, I believe). I'd test it myself, but I'm behind a firewall and getting time outs.

Comment: Removing weekend data gives this message `Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'list')"`

Comment: Can you break down the piping and run your code one row at a time, to see where the problem is? E.g., see what the data that comes out of read_html() looks like.

Comment: yes this is what I have done, Running these lines gives the error: `x <- links %>% 
  sapply(read_html) %>%
  html_table()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to loop through the URL's.  For each one you want to read it, parse it into a data frame, and extracting the first data frame in the list.  So the `read_html()` through `extract2()` steps should be done within the loop.

One option is to use a `purrr::map_dfr()` loop, since it looks like you want to bind things into a single tibble in the end.

Nominally that could look like:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

links %>% 
     map_dfr(~read_html(.x) %>% 
              html_table() %>%
              extract2(1) )
```

However, it turns out that you have missing values that are represented by hyphens (`-`).  Some of the tables have these and some don't.  When these are present, R reads your integer columns as characters while when they are not present integers are read as integer columns.  This causes problems when binding everything together.

I did not see an argument in `read_html()` to deal with these directly (I was looking for the equivalent of `na.strings` in `read.table()` or `na` in `readr::read_csv()`).  My work-around was to convert the hyphens to NA using function `replace_with_na_all()` from package **naniar** (see the [vignette here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/replace-with-na.html)).  Then I converted all columns to the appropriate type with `type.convert()`.

All of this was done within the `map_dfr()` loop.

Here is an example with just the first two URL's in `links`.

```
links[1:2] %>% 
     map_dfr(~read_html(.x) %>% 
              html_table() %>%
              extract2(1) %>%
              naniar::replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x == "-") %>%
              type.convert(as.is = TRUE) )

# A tibble: 15 x 9
   Symbol    Company                     Exchange  Date         `Price Range` Price Currency    Shares Actions 
   <chr>     <chr>                       <chr>     <chr>        <chr>         <dbl> <chr>        <int> <chr>   
 1 2003.HK   Vcredit Hldg Ltd            HKSE      Jun 21, 2018 NA            20    HKD       49969000 Priced  
 2 2003.HK   Vcredit Hldg Ltd            HKSE      Jun 21, 2018 NA            20    HKD       11745600 Priced  
 3 2003.HK   Vcredit Hldg Ltd            HKSE      Jun 21, 2018 NA            20    HKD        6857200 Priced  
 4 0000      Vcredit Hldg Ltd            HKSE      Jun 12, 2018 NA            NA    HKD             NA Expected
 5 6571.JP   QB Net Holdings Co Ltd      Japan OTC Mar 14, 2018 21.11 - 21.11 NA    Y          9785900 Expected
 6 1621.HK   Vico Intl Hldg Ltd          HKSE      Mar 05, 2018 NA             0.35 HKD      175000000 Priced  
 7 PZM.AX    Piston Mach Ltd             ASX       Mar 05, 2018 0.32 - 0.32   NA    AU        50000000 Expected
 8 ""        Agp Ltd                     Karachi   Mar 05, 2018 0.76 - 0.76   80    PKR        8750000 Priced  
 9 GRC.L     GRC International Group PLC LSE       Mar 05, 2018 0.98 - 0.98    0.7  GBP        8414286 Priced  
10 ACPH.BR   Acacia Pharma Group PLC     Brussels  Mar 05, 2018 3.24 - 4.16    3.6  EUR        3175413 Priced  
11 ACPH.BR   Acacia Pharma Group PLC     Brussels  Mar 05, 2018 3.24 - 4.16    3.6  EUR        7935698 Priced  
12 GCI.AX    Gryphon Capital Income Tr   ASX       May 23, 2018 1.57 - 1.57    2    AUD       87650000 Priced  
13 GCI.AX    Gryphon Capital Income Tr   ASX       May 04, 2018 1.57 - 1.57   NA    AUD       50000000 Expected
14 STRL.L    Stirling Inds Plc           LSE       Mar 06, 2018 1.40 - 1.40    1    GBP        8881002 Priced  
15 541006.BO Angel Fibers Ltd            BSE       Mar 06, 2018 NA            27    INR        6408000 Priced
```

Comment: Thanks @aosmith I have this working also! this is a big help so thank you. This site is as helpful as ever!

Comment: It works great but I am getting a subscript out of bounds error when I try to load in more data. I have edited my original post to show the code. `Error in extract2(., 1) : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: The data goes back quite far for example `https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2010-02-01` - February 2010 but I can not seem to access this info. Including the year `2000` - `https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/ipo?day=2000-01-27`

Comment: @user113156 The error is because some of the dates return no info (maybe access issue) and `extract2()` errors when it gets an empty list.  You could capture the error and return something else.  For example, using `purrr::possibly` you could make a function wrapper for `extract2()` that returns `NA` when there is no info.  Example: `poss_extract2 = possibly(extract2, data_frame(Date = NA))` and then use `poss_extract2` in place of `extract2`.  You can test the approach with `links[477]` of your newest example.